# App build failed !!! can't resolve the issue . It is showing Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)[1]

here is the link of screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKQtB.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you click on the hierarchy, then you'll get more information about the error (try clicking on the `NewsRoomDatabase.java` tab)

Comment: What kotlin version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by changing the **JDK location** to Java 1.8

Download Java 1.8 separately. And click **Project Structure**  and change **JDK location**

I hope, I could help.

[image: Click on Project Structure]

[image: Change Jdk location]